# How to dynamically add multiple pieces of data in Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a Jasper Report I am working on in Java.

In Java I can dynamically populate a bean with data with the following code:

```
    List<ThemeBean> themes = new ArrayList<ThemeBean>();
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
    List<String[]> data = csvReader.readAll();
    for(String[] d : data) {
        ThemeBean tb = new ThemeBean();
        tb.setThemes(d[0]);
        tb.setComments(d[1]);
        tb.setSentiment(d[2]);
        themes.add(tb);
    }   
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(fileName);
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(themes);
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, ds);
```

This works well when the .jrxml file has the correct fields specified and textFieldExpression within the  tags...

The following gets dynamically populated with the List that was built:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{themes}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

My problem is figuring out how to do this Dynamically for two different tables in the same report.  It seems that I can only use  for one iteration of data to be dynamically added.  I am trying to achieve a result where I have two completely different tables generated within the same report. If this question isn't clear, please let me know and I will attempt to fix it.  Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand your question as I use and older version of Jasper, and I don't really deal with the underlying architecture as it is already implemented in our system, but maybe what you're looking to use are subreports.

Comment: What means "two different data set"? <br/>
1. Is it attempt to use List<ThemeBean> and List<AnotherBean> in one report? And display all records in one table? <br/>
2. Or is attempt using List<ThemeBean> for first execution and List<AnotherBean> for second execution? With one field $F{themes}

Comment: It is an attempt to use List<ThemeBean> in one table, and List<AnotherBean> is a different table but all in the same report

Answer (score 0):

Jasper ideology: one report - one DataSource.

Use 2 subreport in main report.
Main.jrxml contains subreport1 (for display List<ThemeBean>) and subreport2 (for List<AnotherBean>). Subreport1 and Subreport2 put into Title (or Summary) band.

Define parameters in Main.jrxml : themesPar, anotherPar as java.util.Collection

Put collection as parameters into main report:

```
List<ThemeBean> themes = new ArrayList<ThemeBean>();
themes.add(...);
...
List<AnotherBean> blablas = new ArrayList<AnotherBean>();
blablas.add(...);
...

HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("themesPar", themes);
parameters.put("anotherPar", blablas);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

For subreport1 Data Source Expression in main report write like

```
new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{themesPar})
```

and use the same way with $P{anotherPar} for subreport2.
In both cases set for subreports

```
Connection Type = "Use a datasource expression"
```

Why any novice ask this question??? :)
Why this solution not present in jasperforge FAQ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple bean collections to a report by creating another bean that holds a beanCollection. Such a bean would look like this:

```
public class DataBean {
    private Collection beanCollection = null;

    public DataBean() {
    }

    public Collection getBeanCollection() {
        return beanCollection;
    }

    public void setBeanCollection(Collection beanCollection) {
        this.beanCollection = beanCollection;
    }
}
```

I assume that the other collection will be of a different type than `ThemeBean`. I'm using `FruitBean` as an example. For each bean collection you want to pass, you create a `DataBean` and add it to a collection, then pass *that* collection to the report. So your code would change to be something like this:

```
List<DataBean> allData = new ArrayList<DataBean>();

//...Create and populate `List<ThemeBean> themes`

DataBean db = new DataBean();
db.setBeanCollection(themes);
allData.add(db);

//...Create and populate `List<FruitBean> fruits`

db = new DataBean();
db.setBeanCollection(fruits);
allData.add(db);

//... Load the report
JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(allData);
//... Fill the report
```

The report that you fill with this datasource will be a shell report, containing a subreport for each `DataBean` you created. There will only be one field available in this report: `$F{beanCollection}`

Set the datasource expression of the subreport(s) to

`new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{beanCollection})`.

The fields for `ThemeBean` or `FruitBean` will then be available within the subreport.

If you prefer to use list components instead of subreports, that would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Jasper ideology: one report - one DataSource.

Use 2 subreport in main report. Main.jrxml contains subreport1 (for display List) and subreport2 (for List). Subreport1 and Subreport2 put into Title (or Summary) band.

Define parameters in Main.jrxml : themesPar, anotherPar as java.util.Collection