# Passing field values to table component

Tags: jasper-reports, datasource

I have a problem with a report, I pass a array of values to report (from *Java* code) and that information is loaded inside the report (that works fine). But, I need to pass that field values to a table component, I saw and I can pass parameters to table, but I need use the main field values inside of  table component and print that data there (in table component).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you pass the data from java as datasource. You have to pass the datasource for the table in a parameter and run the report with a different datasource (may be empty if you don't need any data). Then set the table datasource to be that parameter and declare the fields in the subdataset of the table.

See 
[How to show JRBeanCollectionDataSource data with help of Table component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340535/how-to-show-jrbeancollectiondatasource-data-in-ireport-table/22345903#22345903) 
or
[Two DataSource in report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045124/two-datasource-in-report/22146977#22146977)
for examples.